How to show percentage in each plot?
When trying to plot the following code I got 4 graphs but the percentage shows in only in the last graph.
fig, axes =plt.subplots(12,2,figsize=(12,50))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.9, hspace=0.9)
i=0
total = len(data['work_year']) 

for fea_name in fea:
     ax= axes[i//2, i%2]
     i += 1
     sns.countplot(x=fea_name, data=data, ax=ax,palette='icefire' )
     ax.set_title(f'Countplot of {fea_name}')

for i in range(len(fea), 12 * 2):
    fig.delaxes(axes[i//2, i%2])

for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height() / total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width()/3
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()+50
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Showing percentage in only one graph

Before the line for p in ax.patches: you forgot for ax in axes.flat:.

You can simplify your code a bit via ax.bar_label().
(Seaborn's latest version wants hue= equal to the x= column when using a palette.)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first, create some reproducible test data
data = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': np.random.choice([*'abc'], 200),
                     'feature2': np.random.choice([*'defg'], 200),
                     'feature3': np.random.choice([*'hij'], 200),
                     'feature4': np.random.choice([*'klmno'], 200)})
fea = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 12))

total = len(data)

for fea_name, ax in zip(fea, axes.flat):
    sns.countplot(x=fea_name, data=data, ax=ax, hue=fea_name, palette='icefire')
    ax.set_title(f'Countplot of {fea_name}')
    for c in ax.containers:
        ax.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: f'{x / total:.1%}')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



When I tried to run this code, it show me an error 'unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'function' and 'float''

I tested with seaborn 0.13.2 and matplotlib 3.8.3.

fig, axes =plt.subplots(12,2,figsize=(12,50))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.9, hspace=0.9)
i=0
total = len(data['work_year']) 

for fea_name in fea:
     ax= axes[i//2, i%2]
     i += 1
     sns.countplot(x=fea_name, data=data, ax=ax,palette='icefire' )
     ax.set_title(f'Countplot of {fea_name}')
    #  ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

for i in range(len(fea), 12 * 2):
    fig.delaxes(axes[i//2, i%2])
for ax in axes.flat:
    for p in ax.patches:
        percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height() / total)
        x = p.get_x() + p.get_width()/3
        y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()+50
        ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
